# Tailwind / justify-between is not working

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

```
<div class="px-3 py-4 flex items-center justify-between w-full">
        <div class="flex items-center space-x-4">
            <button class="text-2xl px-4 p-3 flex items-center justify-center">
            trial
            </button>
            <button v-for="item in tabNames" @click="selectedTab = item.key" type="button" name="button" :class="`${selectedTab == item.key ? 'rounded-lg border-2' : 'text-gray-400'} py-3 px-5 font-semibold `">
                {{ item.name }}
            </button>
            <div class="flex-grow relative">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass absolute"></i>
                <input class="rounded-lg p-3 w-full sm:w-80" placeholder="search" type="text">
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
```

justify-center, justify-end and justify-start are working as expected but I can't use justify-between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying `justify-content: space-between` on the top-level would not have any observable effect since there is only one element child. Likewise with the `<button>`.

If you meant applying `justify-content: space-between` to the second-level `<div>`, then you'd need to increase the width of this second-level `<div>` element such that it is wider than the sum of the widths of its children (such as by applying `width: 100%`) and also remove `flex-grow: 1` from the `<input>`-wrapping `<div>` to see the `justify-content: space-between` have an observable effect:

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      tabNames: [
        { key: 'foo', name: 'Foo' },
        { key: 'bar', name: 'Bar' },
      ],
      selectedTab: 'foo',
    };
  },
}).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.18/vue.global.prod.min.js" integrity="sha512-nAbjf0Mre6SLZKFZA5W4WphHiJfnopS2GyGFDVoqldP6j+NCWAtImgdW7CWW4CgKiv4MQj3HFaBj5TJri8STSQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div id="app">
  <div class="px-3 py-4 flex items-center justify-between w-full">
    <div class="flex items-center space-x-4 justify-between w-full">
      <button class="text-2xl px-4 p-3 flex items-center justify-center">
        trial
      </button>
      <button v-for="item in tabNames" @click="selectedTab = item.key" type="button" name="button" :class="`${selectedTab == item.key ? 'rounded-lg border-2' : 'text-gray-400'} py-3 px-5 font-semibold `">
        {{ item.name }}
      </button>
      <div class="relative">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass absolute"></i>
        <input class="rounded-lg p-3 w-full sm:w-80" placeholder="search" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```